# Mixing decltype and enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11

It seems that using `decltype` with SFINAE `enable_if` isn't straightforward. I tried writing the `go` using `enable_if` in three different ways. All of them failed with a compiler error (With GCC literally: "error: 'thing' is not a member of 'foo'" and an instantiation context).

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {
  enum { has_thing = false };
};

struct bar {
  enum { has_thing = true };
  static int thing() { return 0; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Test {
  /*auto go(typename std::enable_if<T::has_thing, int>::type=0) 
  -> decltype(T::thing()) {
    return T::thing();
  }*/

  /*typename std::enable_if<T::has_thing, decltype(T::thing())>::type go() {
    return T::thing();
  }*/

  template <bool B=T::has_thing, typename std::enable_if<B, int>::type = 0>
  auto go() -> decltype(T::thing()) {
     return T::thing();
  }
};

int main() {
  Test<bar> b;
  Test<foo> f;
}
```

I can see what the problem is - `decltype` needs to happen before the `enable_if` even gets a chance to rule out the function. The question that remains is how to work around and get similar behaviour? Is there a simple, generic way to do this without resorting to writing  `has_thing` trait to use in the `enable_if`?

Tested with both G++ 4.7 and clang++ 3.0.

Comment: Can you post the compiler error? Also, compiler version would help. I can say from experience that compilers are still extremely buggy in this department.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFINAE will work if the `go` method is a template method:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
  template <class U = T>
  auto go() -> decltype(U::thing()) {
     return T::thing();
  }
};
```

You could also use the `has_thing` value, but there's no need to do it, since SFINAE will take care of that on the above example:

```
template <class U = T, typename std::enable_if<U::has_thing, int>::type = 0>
auto go() -> decltype(U::thing()) {
   return T::thing();
}
```

Then:

```
int main() {
  Test<bar> b;
  Test<foo> f;

  b.go(); // Works!
  f.go(); // Fails!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now that the problem is T wasn't participating in SFINAE even in the third version I tried. The `has_thing` value isn't a boolean in my real code - it picks different versions of the same code based on performance characteristics of different implementations

Answer (score 0):

Of course your SFINAE doesn't work. The `go` function is *not a template*, so no SFINAE can ever apply. Other than that it should work fine with `decltype` (you actually don't need any `has_thing` flag).

Eg. this works fine (and plays nicely with other overloads):

```
template <class U>
auto go(Test<U> t)
  -> decltype(U::thing()) {
  return U::thing();
}
```

Comment: The third version (which is uncommented) in the question definitely is a template, although judging from the other answer I can see that T wouldn't be participating in SFINAE. (`has_thing` is an example here - in the real code it describes the performance characteristics as well as just the existence of `thing`